# Should gradle.properties in Cocos2d-x project with keystore passwords be placed in git or .gitignore?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

With Cocos2d-x 3.15.1, I am using the following command to build release APK in Windows 10:

```
cocos compile -s src/MyProject -p android -m release -o src/MyProject/bin --android-studio
```

On first run it asks for keystore path and keystore passwords. Then it creates file `proj.android-studio\app\gradle.properties` where passwords are stored.

Obviously I don't want to store passwords in source control (git). **Should I put this file (gradle.properties) in .gitignore or I need to somehow move these passwords out of project folder? If need to move out, then how?**

**Note:** I tried to put this file under `C:\Users\MyUser\.gradle\` (as other answers have suggested) but it gets ignored by `cocos compile` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `gradle.properties` in `.gitignore` so that file untracked in your VCS.

Either you can use `Android Studio` to release `.apk`, You can use

Build -> Generate Signed Apk -> Choose Key store and fill password -> Finish

By above process you don't required to put keystore and password in `gradle.properties` file

Comment: 1) The question was "should I put in .gitignore"... What happens if Cocos2d-x adds some important values to gradle.properties? Other team members won't see them... Are you sure that only keystore related values are kept threre?. 2) I am building from command line, so Android Studio is not an option.

Comment: `gradle.properties` are required file for building project, team member who is accessing your project need to create `gradle.properties` in project. File is already in `.gitignore` so ignored in VCS.

Comment: `build.gradle` uses `target sdk`, `jvmargs`, `armeabi` and other data from `gradle.properties` apart from `keystore location` and `password`